# File size exceeds default size during uploading

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working in ASP.NET MVC. I am trying to upload a file, which is successful in case of small files, but if file size is large, I get following error.

```
Maximum request length exceeded.
```

Following is my form.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Method","Controller",FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Following is controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(HttpFileBase file)
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), file.FileName);

    file.SaveAs(path);
}
```

Same code works fine when file is small size i.e. of 1-2Mb, but i am trying to upload a file of 19Mb which is not being uploaded. I don't know how to specify file length and how to remove above mentioned error. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum request length exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Answer (score 1):

In your web.config under System.Web node specify

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="NNN" />
```

Where NNN is file-size in Kbytes

Comment: I found error in following code, when it is requested from browser.'<system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15000" />'

Comment: @FakharuzZaman : you are doing it wrong . there should be only one httpRuntime node there . like <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="15000" />

Answer (score 1):

in your `web.config` file under `system.web` add these settings :

```
<system.web>
  ....
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="XXXX" executionTimeout="XXXX" />
  ....
</system.web>
```

`maxRequestLength` is in **kb** and `executionTimeout` in **minute** . you should set `executionTimeout` to give it enough time to upload file .

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded) for more details .

Answer (score 1):

You can change the max upload size using the web.config as suggested here, but I'd recommend binding that change to the exact URL you expect it to be uploaded to. For example, this changes the max upload size to 50MB.

```
<location path="Documents/Upload">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```